# Minutes by latex: how to reduce space between parts article-class in the listoftopics (toc)?

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, renewcommand

I use `\usepackage{minutes}` to write a minute, by using article-class.
The default style of the article-class I find it best! It looks very nice except for the large space in the  list of topics. In the article-class `\part` corresponds to `\topic`, `\section` to `\subtopic` an so on.. `minutes` package. Instead of a table of contents, it'll show you the list of topics.

But how can a change the space in this list of topics (Tagesordnung in german or Traktanden) to have it so in a much more manageable size? Can I manage it by changing a variable like `\l@part` by application of `\renewcommand`, like something like

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\l@part}{\addvspace{-1pt}}
\makeatother
```

Mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minutes}
\begin{document}

\begin{Protokoll}{Protokoll Versammlung}

\moderation{Vorname \textsc{Name}}
\protokollant{Vorname \textsc{Name}}
\sitzungsdatum{Samstag, 01.01.2022}

\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{Traktanden}   %Change the title of the list of topics
\maketitle{}                           %Output the list of topics
                                       %Not exactly the same as \tableofcontents


\topic{Topic a}
%\subtopic{Unterpunkt zu Top eins}

\topic{Topic b}
%\subtopic{Genehmigung}

\topic{Topic c}
\subtopic{Subtopic c}
\end{Protokoll}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `minutes` uses `minitoc` to create the list of topics.

Setting `\tightmtctrue` makes the list tighter.

By adding a patch it can be made even tighter.

**Default**

[image: a]

**\tightmtctrue** (`\parsep=0pt`)

[image: b]

**\tightmtctrue  + patch** (`\parsep=-2pt`)

[image: c]

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minutes}

%%%*****************************************************
\tightmtctrue % a more compact list

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\ptc@verse}{\iftightmtc\parsep=\z@\fi}{\iftightmtc\parsep=-2pt\fi}{}{}% even more compact <<<<
\makeatother
%%*****************************************************


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Protokoll}{Protokoll Versammlung}
        
        \moderation{Vorname \textsc{Name}}
        \protokollant{Vorname \textsc{Name}}
        \sitzungsdatum{Samstag, 01.01.2022}
        
        \renewcommand{\ptctitle}{Traktanden}   %Change the title of the list of topics
        \maketitle{}                           %Output the list of topics
        %Not exactly the same as \tableofcontents
        
        
        \topic{Topic a}
        %\subtopic{Unterpunkt zu Top eins}
        
        \topic{Topic b}
        %\subtopic{Genehmigung}
        
        \topic{Topic c}
        \subtopic{Subtopic c}
    \end{Protokoll}
\end{document}
```

Comment: YESS !! This works.
Thank you very very much! I spent my hole day to solve the problem. Very good.
thx !